# What does an inode for a socket contain?

Tags: linux, tcp, socket, inode

I read somewhere that the inode for a TCP socket would contain the buffer space.  Is that true, and if so, does it mean that the inode contains a memory address for the buffer space used by the socket, or does it mean a disk address (blocks) for which to buffer tcp data?

Comment: TCP sockets have no on-disk inodes, but UNIX sockets do.  Could you find the document you are remembering?